# Sencha Touch + PhoneGap not finding PhoneGap API

Tags: cordova, extjs, touch

I am new in Apps World, and I started developing with Sencha Touch + PhoneGap.
I think I installed everything right following these: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/cordova and http://vimeo.com/76568053.

My setup:

- Windows 7 x64
- GIT 1.9.4.msysgit.0
- NODEJS 1.4.9
- RUBY 2.0.0p481
- Sencha Touch 2.3.1
- Sencha Cmd 5.0.0.160
- Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.4
- PhoneGap 3.5.0-0.20.4
- ANT 1.9.4
- SASS
- COMPASS
- ANDROID ADK

Both are the last versions up-to-now. All paths set!

After that I created my new app following both links steps.

1. sencha -sdk mypath/touch-2.3.1 generate app TestCordova TestCordova
2. sencha cordova init com.sencha.TestCordova
3. I opened the app.js and put inside launch: function() the line: alert(device.uuid); So I can access the device UUID that cordova API gives.
4. Then I entered in the cordovas folder and write in cmd: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
5. Finally I returned the folder and write: sencha app build -run native

That works perfectly, it opened the emulator and appears the UUID and then the Sencha default app.

The problem comes when I tried to work with PhoneGap, I did the same steps:

1. sencha -sdk mypath/touch-2.3.1 generate app TestPhoneGap TestPhoneGap
2. sencha phonegap init com.sencha.TestPhoneGap
3. I opened the app.js and put inside launch: function() the line: alert(device.uuid); So I can access the device UUID that phonegap API gives.
4. Then I entered in the phonegaps folder and write in cmd: phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
5. Finally I returned the folder and write: sencha app build -run native

The device UUIDS doesn't appeared. When I use if(Ext.browser.is.PhoneGap) it returns false.
What is the problem? Why in cordova works and in phonegap it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Check that `cordova.js` (probably best now with 3.5.0+) or `phonegap.js` are being loaded in your `app.json` file. Needs to load before sencha touch ...

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "cordova.js",
        "remote": true
    },
    {
        "path": "touch/sencha-touch.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "bootstrap.js",
        "x-bootstrap": true
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true,  /* Indicates that all class dependencies are concatenated into this file when build */
        "update": "delta"
    }
],
```

To get you started you might like to try the [Sencha Touch Live](https://github.com/tohagan/stlive) app I wrote that will create, compile, deploy and run a Sencha Touch + PhoneGap app that you can then "live edit" changes into the device or emulator.

A simple way to get started debugging is to use [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) Android simulator with Android 4.4+ so you can use Chrome's remote debugger from your desktop computer. Just open `chrome://inspect` and select the active instance of your app on the attached device or emulator.  Can do the same with recent Safari/iOS.  See installation details below.  This should help you to set breakpoints and diagnose the fault.

You might also fine the detailed [installation check list](https://github.com/tohagan/stlive/blob/master/INSTALL.md) helpful.